# Apply a set of missing function to a data set in R

Tags: r, validation, missing-data, r-mice, imputation

Recently I have came across the package **validate** in R which is very useful when you want to validate a full data set with pre-defined rules, say for example:

```
v <- validator(
Species.na = !is.na(Species),
Species.range = Species %in% c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"),
Sepal.Width.na = !is.na(Sepal.Width),
Sepal.Width.range = Sepal.Width >= 2 & Sepal.Width <= 4,
Sepal.Length.relation = Sepal.Length/Petal.Length < 4)

valied <- confront(iris, v)
```

Now I was wondering if something similar is available with missing value imputation. There are packages like **mice**, **mi** etc. which are really nice but imputation methods are standard, not user defined or custom. Can anyone suggest if there is anyway to set some pre-defined missing functions and apply them to a R data.frame. Something which could work like :

```
m <- missing(
Species.na = if(is.na(Species)) Species <- "setosa"
Sepal.Width.na = if(is.na(Sepal.Width)) Sepal.Width <- 3.5)

mi <- confront(iris, m)
```

Comment: How is this different than `ifelse(is.na(iris$Species), "setosa", iris$Species)` etc?

Comment: The `mice` package actually allows setting up user-defined functions for imputations. There is an article about `mice` in the Journal of Statistical Software that illustrates the general procedure. You can also have a look at the functions already implemented in the `mice` package. They have a common structure.

Comment: I was able to use the validator() function along with the confront() function to accomplish my objective. This package is really cool.